# Outbound SSO in Salesforce with telephony system

Tags: single-sign-on

Can somebody tell me how to do single sign on in salesforce and third party telephony service? 
i want to login in my salesforce with my username and password but to sign in telephony i need username and extension number of agent...
i am getting confused whether is it possible with SSO or not?

Answer (score 0):

This not valid use case for SSO, this is the definition provided by SF for SSO in their SSO implementation guide. Single sign-on (SSO) lets users access authorized network resources with one login. You validate
usernames and passwords against your corporate user database or other client apps rather than
Salesforce managing separate passwords for each resource. It seems to me this use case for integration, but need more information to confirm 100%.